# How copy data from one database to another on different server?

Tags: database, oracle, testing, backup, sqlplus

I have 2 DB with the same schema on different servers.
I need to copy data from table T to the same table T in test database in different server and network.

What is the easiest way to do it?
I heard that data can be dumped to flat file and than inserted into database. How does it works?
Can this be achieved using sqlplus and oracle database?

Thank you!

Comment: might want to look at rsync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Oracle export to export a whole table to a file, copy the file to serverB and import.

```
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ
```

You can use rsync to sync an oracle .dbf file or files to another server.  This has problems and syncing all files works more reliably.

For groups of records, write a query to build a pipe-delimited (or whatever delimiter suits your data) file with  rows you need to move.  Copy that file to serverB.  Write a control file for sqlldr and use sqlldr to load the rows into the table.  sqlldr is part of the oracle installation.

```
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/oracle-sqlldr/
```

If you have db listeners up on each server and tnsnames knows about both, you can directly:

```
insert into mytable@remote 
select * from mytable
  where somecolumn=somevalue;
```

Look at the remote table section:

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm
```

If this is going to be an ongoing thing, create a db link from instance@serverA to instance@serverB.
You can then do anything you have permissions for with data on one instance or the other or both.

```
http://psoug.org/definition/CREATE_DATABASE_LINK.htm
```