# Dump Import vs Parallel Processing vs Hadoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, parallel-processing

Actually I want to copy 50 GB of database from one one server to another server, I just want to know that which one of three options is best.

Thanks

Comment: Best is open to interpretation; without a predefined determinant for ascribing the epithet "best" to an option there's no way to answer this question "well". Having said that, 50GB isn't that much. expdp, rsync, impdp should be fine. I'd normally split it up slightly to take maximum advantage of the network.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to transform the data, can't see any gain by using Hadoop (or parallel processing, for that matter) in this scenario.

See [this question on copying Oracle data between servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595333/how-copy-data-from-one-database-to-another-on-different-server)