# Copy specific tables from db1 into db2 on different server in psql

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, psql

I have 2 databases running psql on 2 servers. To free some space on db1, I would copy the following tables from db1 to db2: `logs_foo` ; `logs_bar` ; `logs_baz`.

To keep consistency in our Rails application, I would keep the same name above in the db2. Obviously, once the transfer is done, I will delete the 3 tables on db1. db1 is set as a "primary" db and db2 will contain only `logs_*`.
I already made changes in my Rails application and all new "logs" goes into the proper `logs_*` table.

Whats is the best way to copy a table from db1 into db2 on 2 differents servers? Should we go with a script? Better in Rails or bash ? Ca I do it in a soft like Dbeaver?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595333/how-copy-data-from-one-database-to-another-on-different-server](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) This one talk about Oracle soft but it was post in 2012...

I though to create a copy of `logs_foo` named `logs_foo1` in db1 and after moving `logs_foo1`in db2, I'll rename or copy it into `logs_foo`. This way is so time consuming and I'll lost some logs wrote in production.

I also could copy the whole db1 as a file and put it in db2 then deleting all the useless data but I don't think it's the proper way to do it.

Comment: 1) You are not running `psql` as that the Postgres command line program. You are running two Postgres instances. 2) The docs are there for a reason. See [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html): *-t pattern Dump only tables with names matching pattern. Multiple tables can be selected by writing multiple -t switches. ...*

Comment: => 1) Yes as you said I ran 2 postgres instances because I have 2 db on 2 differentes servers. => 2) Tanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: What you said is *... 2 databases running psql on 2 servers.*. `psql` is the Postgres command line client, not the Postgres server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-pgdump.html) and restore method. Kindly check below commands

**Export table level:**

```
pg-dump -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -t table database > path/table_name.sql
```

**Import same table into target site:**

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 database < path/table_name.sql
```